# How to vertically align image with flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know its been answered, but none of the answers work for me.

HTML:

```
<div class="sm-col md-col-8 col-12">
  <div class="horizontal-flex">
    <div class="vertical-flex">
      <img class="inline gallery-image-max" src="<%= picture.dir %><%= picture.filename %>">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
 .vertical-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.horizontal-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[image: Example]

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `align-items:center`

```css
.vertical-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /*vertical align*/
  justify-content: center; /*horizontal align*/
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-flex">
  <img class="inline gallery-image-max" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added height to class=Horizontal-flex. It worked like a charm :) It needed height.

Comment: The problem that appears now is that div with class horizontal-flex doesn't get height: 100% :/